# How to get all four corners of Minimum Bounding Rectangle from Boost Envelope?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I'm using the boost [return envelope](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/envelope/return_envelope.html) function to find a minimum bounding rectangle around a set of 2d points. It returns a [box](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_box.html) which has two member functions, `max_corner()` and `min_corner()`.

I would like to know all four corners of the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) of my set of points so I'm a bit confused. Is two corners really enough to define a rectangle? Surely, given two points in space, there are infinitely many rectangles that could fit?

How can I get all four vertices of the MBR?

Comment: If you were expecting the "true" minimum rectangle around the points, then unfortunately boost does not have that function. A search for "point cloud OBB" should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`return_envelope()` creates what's known as an Axis Aligned Bounding Box (AABB).

This means that the edges of the rectangle are assumed to be aligned with the X and Y axises, which greatly restricts the set of rectangles that a pair of points can represent.

Given the bottom-left and top-right corners of the rectangle, aka the corner holding the smallest and largest values for x and y, the other two corners can be determined easily:

```
(min_corner[0], min_corner[1])
(min_corner[0], max_corner[1])
(max_corner[0], min_corner[1])
(max_corner[0], max_corner[1])
```